# Searching text file for specific user-inputted string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to write a program which opens a `text` file full of words (a "dictionary" minus the definitions) and stores these values in strings to compare them against a user input to determine whether the user input is spelled correctly.

I go the program to work and do what I wanted, but I can't seem to figure out one specific detail. I want the program to continue running until the user enters "exit" as an input. The only problem is that my program continues spewing out either `"input is spelled correctly"` or `"input is not spelled correctly"` ad infinitum without giving the user a chance to input more values in.

How do I make it so the program only outputs one of these two options only once and then prompts the user for another input instead of a never-ending stream of the same statement? Thank you in advanced!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line; //holds values from txt file
    string input; //holds user-inputted values
    ifstream inputFile; //fstream operator declaration
    bool isFound = false; //bool value to indicate if the string has been found

    inputFile.open("dict.txt", ios::in);

    if (inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Enter word to spellcheck (or exit to end)\n";
        getline(cin, input);

        while (input != "exit")
        {
            while (getline(inputFile, line))
            {
                if (input == line)
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    isFound = false;
                }
            }

            inputFile.close();

            if (isFound)
            {
                cout << input << " is spelled correctly.\n";
            }

            else
            {
                cout << input << " is not spelled correctly.\n";
            }
        }

        if (input == "exit")
        {
            cout << "Ending program...\n";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inputFile.close();` sitting in the middle of the main loop sure doesn't help. Recommend reading the file into a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) once at the beginning, and then searching the set for matches.

Comment: I moved the closing statement out of the way to the bottom of the main loop as well as moved the `while (input != "exit")` before the input and now i'm getting the problem that all words are marked incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Inside the body of the

```
while (input != "exit")
```

loop the user is never asked to update the value of input. Moving `getline(cin, input)` into the while condition like this:

```
while (getline(cin, input) && input != "exit")
```

will solve that problem.

Then next problem is the handling of the dictionary file. It is closed in the middle of the loop, so subsequent reads from it will instantly fail. OP could reset the read pointer to the beginning of the file with [`inputFile.seekg(0);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), but why reread the file every time.

Instead read the dictionary file into a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) with more or less the same code as used in the search:

```
std::set<std::string> dictionary;
while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    dictionary.insert(line);
}
```

at the beginning of the program and search the set for the user's input in the loop.

```
if (dictionary.find(input) != dictionary.end())
{
    cout << input << " is spelled correctly.\n";
}
else
{
    cout << input << " is not spelled correctly.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you just need to move your getline block in the while loop, and move the file close statement outside the while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line; //holds values from txt file
    string input; //holds user-inputted values
    ifstream inputFile; //fstream operator declaration
    bool isFound = false; //bool value to indicate if the string has been found

    inputFile.open("dict.txt", ios::in);

    if (inputFile)
    {

        while (input != "exit")
        {
            // Rewind file back to beginning every time
            inputFile.clear();
            inputFile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg); 

            cout << "Enter word to spellcheck (or exit to end)\n";
            getline(cin, input);
            while (getline(inputFile, line))
            {
                if (input == line)
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    isFound = false;
                }
            }


            if (isFound )
            {
                cout << input << " is spelled correctly.\n";
            }

            else
            {
                if (input != "exit"){ // Don't print message if exiting
                    cout << input << " is not spelled correctly.\n";
                }
            }
        }

        if (input == "exit")
        {
            cout << "Ending program...\n";
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're reading from the file, you'll have to rewind the file every loop. Otherwise `while (getline(inputFile, line))` will keep hitting the end of the file and never find a match.

Comment: Nice catch, updated the answer! Also disabled the "not correct" message when exiting the program.